# Home Screen widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have to build a flutter app where the data need to be shown on home screen
of the phone, if the app is in background mode.

Till now i have not found any relevant information regarding the home screen widget or how to create the app widget in flutter except the one that

> we can build app widget in native(Android/iOS).
>   [Native widget in android](https://medium.com/android-bits/android-widgets-ad3d166458d3)

Do i need to handle app widget from the native code or is there a way to handle app widget in flutter.

Comment: You'll need to do it in native. And it's quite a tricky topic if you want it to interact with your Flutter app.

Answer (score 6):

It's not official supported, but there are some packages, to do the basic stuff:

https://pub.dev/packages/home_widget

| Android | iOS |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

There is also a ticket in the Flutter repo: [Explore home widgets for iOS 14](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60026#issuecomment-743994073). So you can upvote this ticket, if you are interested.